# Eclipse Jee CSS editor in Eclipse Java

Tags: eclipse, css

I can't seem to associate *.css file types to the CSS Editor in Eclipse Java. I'm trying to use the CSS Editor from Eclipse Jee, but it's not under the Internal Editors list.

How can I achieve this while working within the workbench? I don't want to use an external editor.

Thank you.

Comment: The CSS editor is part of the 'Eclipse Web Developer Tools' - check you have that installed. If not use Install New Software to install it from your main Eclipse site.

Comment: I installed it, and added *.css to my File Associations, and sure enough CSS File Editor was set as the default editor for that file type. It still wasn't listed under internal editors, but it popped up after I entered *.css automatically. Thank you.